# why do these radio buttons act how they do through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I'm just wondering why the first question in my quiz can have radio buttons that are independent from the rest of the questions, but after question 1 all of the questions act as one radio button group?
This is the javascript:

```
window.onload = getQuizXml;

function getQuizXml() {
  var quiz = new XMLHttpRequest();
  quiz.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (quiz.readyState == 4 && quiz.status == 200) {
      searchQuiz(quiz);


    }
  };
  quiz.open("GET", "FinalQuiz.xml", true);
  quiz.send();

}

function searchQuiz(quiz) {

  var i;
  //get data as xml file
  var xmldoc = quiz.responseXML;
  var test = "<form id = 'test'>";
  //start table
  //process data by record
  var x = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("question");
  var errorMessage = "Error, Well does not exist.";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    var questionNumber = x[i].getElementsByTagName("qnumber")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var questionTitle = x[i].getElementsByTagName("qtitle")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var a = x[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var b = x[i].getElementsByTagName("b")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var c = x[i].getElementsByTagName("c")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var d = x[i].getElementsByTagName("d")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    test += "<br>" + questionNumber + "." +
      "<br>" +
      questionTitle +
      "<br><br>" +
      "a)<input type='radio' value='a' name ='question'>" + a +
      "<br>" +
      "b)<input type='radio' value='b' name ='question'>" + b +
      "<br>" +
      "c)<input type='radio' value='c' name ='question'>" + c +
      "<br>" +
      "d)<input type='radio' value='d' name ='question'>" + d +
      "<br></form>";



    document.getElementById("displayquiz").innerHTML = test;

  }

}
```

and this is a sample of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE finalquiz SYSTEM "FinalQuiz.dtd" >
<finalquiz>
  <question>
    <qnumber>1</qnumber>
    <qtitle>In a switch statement, the ________ case clause is used to process exceptional conditions and is usually listed last.</qtitle>
    <a>break</a>
    <b>default</b>
    <c>else</c>
    <d>then</d>
  </question>
  <question>
    <qnumber>2</qnumber>
    <qtitle>The technique of developing and maintaining a large program by constructing it from small, simple pieces is called ________.</qtitle>
    <a>divide and conquer</a>
    <b>modular programming</b>
    <c>multitasking</c>
    <d>multiprogramming</d>
  </question>
  <question>
    <qnumber>3</qnumber>
    <qtitle>All variables declared in function definitions are ________.</qtitle>
    <a>global variables</a>
    <b>static variables</b>
    <c>constant variables</c>
    <d>local variables</d>
  </question>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are grouped using the `name` attribute. I can't see any reason why question 1 would be in a separate group from the rest.

Comment: All your radio buttons have `name='question'`, so they should be one group.

Comment: BTW, you should assign the `innerHTML` after the loop is done, not every time through the loop.

Comment: yea it seemed weird that question 1 is independent..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your radio buttons can be grouped by different form section wrapping. but your string appending logic has a bug for it.
your code's result would be like below:

```
<form>
  <input type='radio' value='a' name ='question'>
  <input type='radio' value='b' name ='question'>
  <input type='radio' value='c' name ='question'>
  <input type='radio' value='d' name ='question'>
</form>
<!-- there is a missing form start tag(<form>) here supposed to be -->
  <input type='radio' value='a' name ='question'>
...
</form>
```

so your code needs to be changed as like below.

```
 var test = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    test += "<form id = 'test'>";        

    ...

    test += "<br>" + questionNumber + "." +
      "<br>" +
      questionTitle +
      "<br><br>" +
      "a)<input type='radio' value='a' name ='question'>" + a +
      "<br>" +
      "b)<input type='radio' value='b' name ='question'>" + b +
      "<br>" +
      "c)<input type='radio' value='c' name ='question'>" + c +
      "<br>" +
      "d)<input type='radio' value='d' name ='question'>" + d +
      "<br></form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute is what separates/groups the radio buttons.

If you look at this from a server side like PHP the value would come through the post of the form looking something like:

```
$_POST['question']
```

If you need to make a new group for another question change the name attribute like so:

```
<form>
  <div id='q1_label'>This is question 1:</div>
  <input type='radio' value='a' name ='question1'><span>A</span><br />
  <input type='radio' value='b' name ='question1'><span>B</span><br />
  <input type='radio' value='c' name ='question1'><span>C</span><br />
  <input type='radio' value='d' name ='question1'><span>D</span><br />
  <div id='q2_label'>This is question 2:</div>
  <input type='radio' value='a' name ='question2'><span>A</span><br />
  <input type='radio' value='b' name ='question2'><span>B</span><br />
  <input type='radio' value='c' name ='question2'><span>C</span><br />
  <input type='radio' value='d' name ='question2'><span>D</span><br />
</form>
```

In other words:

The whole reason for the different values in each group is to provide the posted value for that field name.

server side can now handle this like:

```
$q1 = $_POST['question1'];
$q2 = $_POST['question2'];
```

and then go and compare the passed data against an answer sheet, or something like that.